# how to install libjsoncpp1 in Debian 11 Bullseye

Tags: debian

I am trying to install something which needs libjsoncpp1

I've tried without it and it does indeed fail with an error message.

This library does not seem to exist in Debian Bullseye.

It does however exist in some earlier Debian:

https://packages.debian.org/buster/libjsoncpp1

Does anyone know how to install it in Bullseye?

Comment: Debian Bullseye has the package [libjsoncpp24](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libjsoncpp24).  If that does not satisfy the dependency, then it would probably be easier to use Debian Buster.  You could try building the Buster version of `libjsoncpp1` for Bullseye if you know how `.deb`s are packaged.

Comment: Thanks but I already put libjsoncpp24 on there but it was not enough. Do I need to add something to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ? I did play around with that but did not get anywhere.

Comment: If you have a package that requires `libjsoncpp1` and does not accept `libjsoncpp24`, then you would have to use `libjsoncpp1` which would be solved by using Debian Buster.  Adding Buster repositories to your Bullseye install would not be recommended.  If you have to use Bullseye, you would want to build the `libjsoncpp1` package for Bullseye.

Comment: Well I think changing the whole OS to an earlier one for this would take hours and unleash other challenges. Any tips how to build this `libjsoncpp1`  - where would one start?

Comment: The [Debian Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/ro-RO/stable/debian-packaging.html) has a section on rebuilding packages.  If you have to use Bullseye, have you checked if the software you want to use has a package compatible with Bullseye?

Comment: Well, there is an easier but less pure way to install the software I want. Thanks for the link - that looks like an hour or two of intense focus to get that installed. If there is no simpler way to get that package on there I will question whether to install the original software at all or use the other method (flatpack)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev
```

The hint came from here:

https://packages.debian.org/source/bullseye/libjsoncpp